# Manipulating rows from a table

Tags: sql, codeigniter

```
    function getData(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->db->select("t.*, mt.mid as mid, mt.amt as mtamt, m.user");
    $this->db->from("transaction as t");
    $this->db->join("mtrans as mt", "mt.tid = t.id and mt.mid = '$id'", "left outer");
    $this->db->join("member as m", "m.id = mt.aid", "left outer");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data = $query->result_array();

    return $data;
}
```

For starters, this is my code. How do I manipulate it so that `mt.amt` with the same `t.id` and `mt.mid` will be displayed as 1 row showing the sum of all `mt.amt` in the `mt.amt` column?

Comment: About your first join, are you sure of this `"mt.tid = t.id and mt.mid = '$id'"` ? The `and mt.mid = '$id'` doesn't seem right

Comment: It's right. `and mt.mid = '$id'` gets all the data from `t` while only choosing a data from `mt`. If it happens that a row from `t` doesn't contain any link to `mt` it'll only return one row with null on the `mt.amt` column. What I want to filter now is when `mt` returns duplicate, the duplicates merges except for the `mt.amt` since I want them summed up.

Comment: can you show the table and the result that you want?